# Me sale este error cuando trato de validar mi website! Error: Start tag body seen but an element of the same type was already open

Tags: html, css, html5, validación

Error:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>



<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>About me</title>
<link href="../CSS/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">



</head>
<a href="../index.html"><img class="home" src="../images/home.png" width="60" alt="home"></a>

<img class="clip" src="../images/clip.png" width="300" alt="clipe">

<body id="aboutme">



<h1 class="titulo">About me</h1>

    <h2>INFORMATION</h2>
    <aside>
      <ul>
        <h3>Things I love...</h3>
        <li>All kinds of music</li>
        <li>Asian food</li>
        <li>Traveling everywhere</li>
        <li>Taking pictures</li>
        <li>Netflix</li>
      </ul>
    </aside>
      <section>


      <img class="picofme" src="../images/juli.JPG" width="400" alt="Pic of me">
      <p class="mytext"> First of all, thank you for visiting my website. My name is Julian, I am 24 years old and I was born in Bogota, Colombia; a beautiful country in South America. I consider myself a person that is really passionate for the art. Sometimes people ask me what's my favorite field, and I never have a concrete answer. This world is full of many incredible things, that is really hard to choose what I love the most. I wanted to be a singer before, but I realized my talent didn't exist. Even though my singing is horrible, I consider myself a music lover (I can play the guitar). After so many years trying to figure what my passion was, I found the film as the perfect way to express what I feel. There are days in which I wish I knew everything about the film, but then I think everything is a process. I love traveling to different places, and taking pictures of everything. Right now, I am enjoying this stage of my life, where I learn new things every day. "Life is like a ladder where you give steps every day"
      </p>


        <div class="chinatext">
        <img class="china" src="../images/china.JPG" width="400" alt="China">
        <p class="secondtext">
        los largo de 1808, las presiones de Napoleón desencadenaron una serie de acontecimientos que empeoraron aún más la ya comprometida situación española, el rey Carlos IV de España abdicó el trono a favor de su hijo Fernando el 19 de marzo de 1808 después de los sucesos del motín de Aranjuez, y más tarde, el 5 de mayo de 1808 se terminó de consumar el desastre para España cuando Carlos IV y su hijo fueron obligados a ceder el trono a Napoleón Bonaparte en Bayona para designar a su hermano, José, como nuevo rey de España. Esto provocó una gran reacción popular en España que desencadenó lo que hoy se conoce como la guerra de la Independencia española y tanto en América como en España, se formaron juntas regionales que fomentaron la lucha contra los invasores franceses para restablecer en el trono al monarca legítimo.
       </p>
       </div>
       </section>



</body>

</html>
```

Al validar usando el validador  [html5.validator.nu](https://html5.validator.nu/)
From line 18, column 1; to line 18, column 19

> Error: Start tag body seen but an element of the same type was already open.
>
> From line 18, column 1; to line 18, column 19
>
> "clipe">↩↩↩↩↩↩

Comment: ¿Cuando tratas de validarlo con qué? ¿Con tu licuadora? Creo que se necesitan más detalles para poder ayudarte.

Comment: @RuslanLópez con este https://html5.validator.nu/

Comment: PErfecto, ya edito tu pregunta con los detalles relevantes y te agrego una respuesta rápida :)

Comment: No puedes poner ninguna etiqueta html (ni ninguna otra cosa) entre las etiquetas head y body. Fijate que tienes las etiquetas <a> y el <img> alli. Esas etiquetas las tienes que poner dentro del body

Answer (score 1):

El problema está en que tu HTML no cumple con la estructura normal de un HTML, normalmente un HTML tiene máximo una de las siguientes dos secciones:

- head
- body

EL head se usa para comunicarse con el navegador y otros programas (como los robots y crawlers) directamente, así que muchas de las cosas que pongas aquí no serán para tu usuario.

En el body pones las cosas que sean parte de lo que quieras mostrar directamente al usuario.

Dicho esto, el error en concreto que te marca "Start tag body seen but an element of the same type was already open." nos indica que el navegador normalmente creará una etiqueta body por tí si no la pones justo después de terminar tu etiqueta head.

Por lo que aún si recibe únicamente este fragmento, creará contenido visible apra tí:

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>About me</title>
</head>
<a href="../index.html"><img class="home" src="../images/home.png" width="60" alt="home"></a>
<img class="clip" src="../images/clip.png" width="300" alt="clipe">
```

Para corregir tu código asegúrate que tenga la estructura básica:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Sin poner nada entre tu head y tu body, de la siguiente manera:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>



<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>About me</title>
<link href="../CSS/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">



</head>

<body id="aboutme">

<a href="../index.html"><img class="home" src="../images/home.png" width="60" alt="home"></a>

<img class="clip" src="../images/clip.png" width="300" alt="clipe">


<h1 class="titulo">About me</h1>

    <h2>INFORMATION</h2>
    <aside>
      <ul>
        <h3>Things I love...</h3>
        <li>All kinds of music</li>
        <li>Asian food</li>
        <li>Traveling everywhere</li>
        <li>Taking pictures</li>
        <li>Netflix</li>
      </ul>
    </aside>
      <section>


      <img class="picofme" src="../images/juli.JPG" width="400" alt="Pic of me">
      <p class="mytext"> First of all, thank you for visiting my website. My name is Julian, I am 24 years old and I was born in Bogota, Colombia; a beautiful country in South America. I consider myself a person that is really passionate for the art. Sometimes people ask me what's my favorite field, and I never have a concrete answer. This world is full of many incredible things, that is really hard to choose what I love the most. I wanted to be a singer before, but I realized my talent didn't exist. Even though my singing is horrible, I consider myself a music lover (I can play the guitar). After so many years trying to figure what my passion was, I found the film as the perfect way to express what I feel. There are days in which I wish I knew everything about the film, but then I think everything is a process. I love traveling to different places, and taking pictures of everything. Right now, I am enjoying this stage of my life, where I learn new things every day. "Life is like a ladder where you give steps every day"
      </p>


        <div class="chinatext">
        <img class="china" src="../images/china.JPG" width="400" alt="China">
        <p class="secondtext">
        los largo de 1808, las presiones de Napoleón desencadenaron una serie de acontecimientos que empeoraron aún más la ya comprometida situación española, el rey Carlos IV de España abdicó el trono a favor de su hijo Fernando el 19 de marzo de 1808 después de los sucesos del motín de Aranjuez, y más tarde, el 5 de mayo de 1808 se terminó de consumar el desastre para España cuando Carlos IV y su hijo fueron obligados a ceder el trono a Napoleón Bonaparte en Bayona para designar a su hermano, José, como nuevo rey de España. Esto provocó una gran reacción popular en España que desencadenó lo que hoy se conoce como la guerra de la Independencia española y tanto en América como en España, se formaron juntas regionales que fomentaron la lucha contra los invasores franceses para restablecer en el trono al monarca legítimo.
       </p>
       </div>
       </section>



</body>

</html>
```